# Generation of Process definition Id in activiti

Tags: scala, activiti

In Activiti:
  After the model creation,deploy.ProcessDefinition will be generated.In that,the processDefinitionId will be as 'Testprocess:1:577504' .Can any one help me to know that how this will be generated and how the version number will be useful.

```
var processEngine: ProcessEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine()
val repositoryService: RepositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService
val processDefinitions = repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery.deploymentId(577501).list.asScala.toList.map(_.getId)

RESULT:
processDefinitions =List(Testprocess:1:577504)
```

Comment: Do you have code? We can't help you if you don't give us the code you've written. Hard to diagnose a problem.

Comment: You shouldn't care about what the ID is and how it's built.

Comment: @wheaties Please check the code once

Comment: @biziclop I just want to know how the version will be useful.
If i edit the same model and redeploy it ,i am getting different ProcessDefinitionId and it is not allowing me to redeploy with the same processIdentifier.

In that senario how can i have the track of model which has been editted so many times

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the process definition id has the version included, is because process definitions are cached for each Activiti engine.

When you redeploy one one engine, the other engines don't know there is a new versions. Hence, when starting a process instance for a particular process definition, a quick check is made using this id to check if it still is the latest.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of folk have responded, but no-one has actually answered your questions.
1. How is the ID generated?

The ID is generated by one of the following classes depending on your configuration: 
./src/main/java/org/activiti/engine/impl/db/DbIdGenerator.java
./src/main/java/org/activiti/engine/impl/persistence/StrongUuidGenerator.java

2. How is the ID used?
   The use of the ID for a process deployment is to identify the version of the process definition. Long running processes may live for months or years and it is possible for multiple versions of the one process to be active concurrently. Having a unique ID ensures the correct sub processes (called activities), resources and forms (if using form key) are retrieved.

If all you care about launching is the most recently deployed version, you can use the process key in your code and this will ignore the version and simply start the most recent deployment.

Hope this helps.
Greg